# predsort/3 unexpected behavior

Tags: sorting, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a problem sorting a list of tasks `[t7, t1, t6, t2, t4, t3, t5]` in Prolog. To sort this I want to use the predefined formula `predsort/3` as it seems like the correct approach.

My custom predicate looks like this:

```
sort_dependency(<, T, T2) :-
    depends_on(T,T2,_).
sort_dependency(>, T, T2) :-
    depends_on(T2,T,_). 
sort_dependency(>, T, T2) :-
    T == T2;
    not(depends_on(T,T2,_)),
    not(depends_on(T2,T,_)).
```

When testing this I get the following:

```
?- predsort(sort_dependency,  [t7, t1, t6, t2, t4, t3, t5], Sorted).
Sorted = [t5, t4, t3, t7, t2, t6, t1] .
```

This isn't correct. The correct answer should be something like `[t1 , t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t]`.
For testing purpose here are the facts of `depends_on`.

```
depends_on(t7,t2,0).
depends_on(t7,t6,0).
depends_on(t6,t4,0).
depends_on(t6,t5,0).
depends_on(t2,t1,0).
depends_on(t4,t3,0).
depends_on(t3,t1,0).
depends_on(t5,t3,0).
```

I tried switching different variables around be still can't get the expected result. Is `keysort/2` a better option? Problem is I don't see how to implement keysort in combination with a custom predicate.

Comment: What does the 3rd clause of `sort_dependency/3` actually mean? I assume it should be `==`. But why should two objects be the same if they do not directly depend on each other?

Comment: To me I read this as, `>` is used as a predicate if both tasks are the same `OR` they are not dependent on each other. It should be equivalent if I just replace it with `sort_dependency(>, T, T2).` because if both previous clauses fail the third will always be true. Problem still remains the same if I do this change.

Comment: The name of this should be rather `compare_xxx` and the first argument has to be `>`, `<` or `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Topological sorting is what you actually want. There is [`top_sort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=top_sort/2) for this.

`predsort/3` assumes a total order, but you can only provide a partial order.

In other words, `predsort/3` will query your supplied comparison predicate. And it expects as answers `<`, `=` or `>`. So you have to produce one exact answers for all pairs of nodes. However, for some, (those that are incomparable) you cannot tell what the result should be. You can only guess, which will not produce a consistent total order.

Comment: Interesting thanks, any idea how to to tell prolog to use the `depends_on` for the `top_sort/2`? Documentation doesn't seem much help for beginners.

Comment: You need to convert the data into a graph and then you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the solution proposed by @false. The tasks are transformed to a graph, edges are set using `depends_on` and then we use `top_sort/2` on the result.

Hope this is useful to some.

```
sort_tasks(ToSort, Sorted) :-
    vertices_edges_to_ugraph(ToSort,[],Gr), %Gr is graph wiht nodes as the tasks
    add_my_edges(Gr, ToSort, GrN),
    top_sort(GrN,Sorted). 

add_my_edges(Gr,[],Gr).
add_my_edges(Gr,[T|TR], GrReturn) :-
    findall(X,depends_on(X,T,_),L), %L moet na T gebeuren
    add_my_edge(Gr, T, L, GrN),
    add_my_edges(GrN,TR,GrReturn).

add_my_edge(Gr, _,[], Gr).
add_my_edge(Gr, T, [LH|LR], GrReturn) :-
    add_edges(Gr, [T-LH], GrN),
    add_my_edge(GrN, T, LR, GrReturn).
```